# Can't compare in ajax

Tags: ajax

```
//From other function
var check = check_abc(a,b,c);
alert (check);


function check_abc(a,b,c)
{

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",

    url: "abc.php",

    data: { a: a, 
            b: b,
            c:  c
        },

    success:function(data) { //alert to get the data and make sure it was return ok.
        if(data == "OK")
        {
            window.alert("YEA");
            goOn();
        }
        else
        {
            window.alert("Testing");
            noGood();
        }
    }
});

}
```

Event though it return "OK" (use alert to check before), but no matter what it never show alert("YEA"), why is it so? The data dont seem to be able to compare

Comment: set **console.log(data)** on next line of success method.

Comment: your data method not return any value that why data=="OK" returns false and code going to else method. first check your server response why you not get Ok or something else.

Comment: well.. the console did return OK. Forget to refresh

Comment: @ManProgrammer it did return but cannot compare. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're (correctly) using an asynchronous AJAX call. When you call `check_abc(a,b,c)`, it immediately returns an undefined value, since the response from the server will come later.

Simplify your calling code to this:

```
//From other function
check_abc(a,b,c);
```

And inside the `success` function itself, display the dialog (which will happen when you get a response from the server):

```
success:function(data) { //alert to get the data and make sure it was return ok.
    var displayBoolean = date === "OK";
    alert(displayBoolean);
}
```

Comment: It is not working.. i am trying to use another method but stuck again. Do help me check (I had update the question). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous that why you can't get value

try like this

```
success:function(data) { //alert to get the data and make sure it was return ok.
        if(data == "OK")
            {catchVal("OK");return true; }   //tried check == true; still cannot
        else
            {catchVal("Error");return false;}
    }

function catchVal(val){
alert(val);
}
```

Comment: Don't return anything from the `success` function (since as you said it's asynchronous).

Comment: i was called catchVal function from the success part and it calling after the response comes from the server

Comment: Right, but you still can't return anything from the `success` function.

Comment: It is not working.. i am trying to use another method but stuck again. Do help me check (I had update the question). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",

    dataType: "text",
    url: "abc.php",

    data: { a: a, 
            b: b,
            c:  c
        },

    success:function(data) {

        var result = $.trim(data);

        if(result == "OK")
        {
            window.alert("YEA");
            goOn();
    }
       else
       {
           window.alert("Testing");
           noGood();
       }
```

Comment: what is your expected output Please tell us?

Comment: Expected output is the popout box appear "YEA" when the data was return "OK" else appear "Testing"

Comment: can you paste your console.log output, put inside the success method.